# Loop through data in a JSONResult

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

Is there a way to loop through JSON results using an index value instead of the key?
I would like to look through the json data result and grab the key and value that was sent over.

e.g.

```
 $.get('/Home/GetTypes', function (data) 
      {
       $.each(function(index) {
           //Just as an example I know this will not work. Thanks
         '<a class="p-button" href="/Wizard/Create/" + data[index][value] + " '">' + data[index][key] + '</a>' 
        }     

       });
```

Comment: what does the JSON string that you're returning look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming data is an array of dictionaries, you're close:

```
 $.each(data, function(index, obj) {
      // then obj and data[index] both point to the nth entry in data
```

Comment: How would this return the key data and the value data? I would think that data[index] would only return the value.

Comment: `index` *is* the key!  Would it be clearer to write it as `$.each(data, function(key, value) {` ?

Comment: Hehe. Thanks I thought that it was passing a numerical index but that is great. Thanks

Comment: If data is an *array*, then yes, the index is numerical; otherwise, it is, you know, whatever...

Answer (score 0):

```
for (key in data) {
    key = the key name
    data[key] = the value
}
```